# Grinder has voltage, but no sound or motion

Tags: motor

I have a coffee grinder which has stopped working.

It shows voltage when measured on the the brushes, but I'm not sure if this simple measurement provides any useful information.

Could it be that one or both of the brushes has stopped working?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The brushes are a wear item. Are they both actually contacting the commutator?

Comment: Replace brushes if they are worn. Wiggle/check that they spring as they should if not. Report back.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany there is contact between the brushes and the commutator. If i pull back any of the two brushes (insert something thin between the commutator and brush), the brush will then be pushed forward against the commutator again.

Comment: @sbrattla It's just a process. One step at a time. Eliminate what isn't the problem and keep tracing things out until you do find the problem. It's possible (I have seen it, personally) where there is a fuse buried deeply into the stator block and surrounded by coil wire, for example. Not easily visible and it took me a while to find it. But it was there and open. Technically, not a replaceable item (very hard to get at) but when replaced, the motor again worked. Not suggesting any of that here. But there is a reason it isn't working. (Apparently not because of your measurement, so far.)

Comment: That looks like a heavy patina on the commutator segments. Has it been standing idle for a year or two? If the brushes are OK, metal polish or 1000 grit emery paper to clear the insulating oxide layer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [universal motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_motor), disconnect it from the power then measure the bits that should conduct to see if they do conduct.

Answer (score 2):

If you are measuring voltage at the brushes, the problem is most likely lack of good contact between the brushes and the commutator. If it is a minor problem, turning the rotor by hand and trying to run with a different starting position will likely get the motor running and prove that is the problem. You will still need to clean up the commutator and perhaps change the brushes to achieve convenient and reliable starting.

Voltage between the brushes proves continuity of the stator winding since the stator is connected in series in a universal motor. If the stator is open, it could be an open thermal fuse embedded in the stator winding. There would not be a thermistor in the rotor winding because there are many parallel paths for current to flow through the rotor winding from one commutator segment to the diametrically opposite segment. The rotor winding is actually a closed loop with a connection to the loop at every commutator segment.

You should examine the brushes carefully to make sure that they are connected. It is possible that one of your voltage measurement points is not actually contacting the brush.